# Dynamically inserting text into html file from java

Tags: java, html

I am very new to java web development, so I have the following issue.I have some pictures in a folder on the server, and I want to dynamically append them to the html file, so they could be displayed on the web page. Is there a way to format html file ?

Here is the desired result:

[image]

Here is the html code I want to add:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="T.jpg">
        <img
        src="https://pmcvariety.files.wordpress.com/2018/07/bradybunchhouse_sc11.jpg?w=1000&h=563&crop=1"
        alt="Forest" />
    </a>
    <h5 class="offer-item-title">
        <a title="детайли"
            href="http://www.kalchev.com/estate/offer/6309">Къща, Варна
            обл., с.Болярци</a>
    </h5>
    <div class="offer-item-title">Триетажна къща с красива
                                панорама към Кране Триетажна къща с красива панорама към Кране</div>
    <h4 class="offer-item-price">110 000&nbsp;€</h4>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="ASD.jpeg">
        <img
        src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--bIV3xkEm--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/jsprifdd1gmfy7e7nola.jpg"
        alt="Northern Lights" />
    </a>
    <h5 class="offer-item-title">
        <a title="детайли"
                                    href="http://www.kalchev.com/estate/offer/6309">Къща, Варна
                                    обл., с.Болярци</a>
    </h5>
    <div class="offer-item-title">Триетажна къща с красива
                                панорама към Кране Триетажна къща с красива панорама към Кране</div>
    <h4 class="offer-item-price">110 000&nbsp;€</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Java or JavaScript - which one are you working in?

Comment: I am working with java

Comment: There are so many ways to deal with that. First of all, you can explore about jsp and servlet. Or you can create json object in java by gson and map it to *.jsp(like HTML but java-related).

Comment: You want a templating technology such as Thymeleaf or Mustache. (Please don't use JSP!)